# How to call PostgreSQL stored procedures from a WSO2 REST dataservice

Tags: postgresql, rest, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

I have a REST data service in WSO2 like this:

```
<data name="RESTDataService" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/json_sample" transports="http https">
  <description>Exponiendo el servicio de datos como un servicio REST.</description>
  <query id="obtenerEdad" useConfig="default">
    <sql>SELECT * FROM verificarEdad(:id_cliente)</sql>
    <param name="id_cliente" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <result outputType="json">
    {
      "cliente": {
        "verificaredad": "$verificaredad"
      }
    }
  </result>
  </query>
  <query id="obtenerEdadCuenta" useConfig="default">
    <sql>SELECT * FROM verificaredadcuenta(:id_cuenta)</sql>
    <param name="id_cuenta" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <result outputType="json">
    {
      "cliente": {
        "verificaredadcuenta": "$verificaredadcuenta"
      }
    }
  </result>
  </query>
  <query id="obtenerEdadSaldo" useConfig="default">
    <sql>SELECT * FROM verificaredadsaldo(:id_cuenta)</sql>
    <param name="id_cuenta" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <result outputType="json">
    {
      "cliente": {
        "verificaredadsaldo": "$verificaredadsaldo"
      }
    }
  </result>
  </query>
  <query id="obtenerDatosClientes" useConfig="default">
    <sql>SELECT * FROM ObtenerDatosCliente(:id_cliente)</sql>
    <param name="id_cliente" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <result outputType="json">
    {
      "cliente": {
        "nombre_completo": "$nombre_completo",
        "domicilio": "$domicilio",
        "numero_cliente": "$numero_cliente"
      }
    }
  </result>
  </query>
  <query id="ObtenerDatosCuenta" useConfig="default">
    <sql>SELECT * FROM obtenerDatosCuenta(:p_cuenta_id)</sql>
    <param name="p_cuenta_id" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <result outputType="json">
      {
        "cuentas": {
          "cuenta": {
            "numero_cuenta": "$numero_cuenta",
            "nombre_banco": "$nombre_banco",
            "sucursal": "$sucursal",
            "vigencia": "$vigencia"
          }
        }
      }
    </result>
  </query>
  <query id="ObtenerDatosSaldo" useConfig="default">
    <sql>SELECT * FROM obtenerDatosSaldo(:p_saldo_id)</sql>
    <param name="p_saldo_id" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <result outputType="json">
      {
        "saldos": {
          "saldo": [
            {
              "fecha": "$fecha",
              "saldo": "$saldo",
              "tipo_movimiento": "$tipo_movimiento"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    </result>
  </query>
  <query id="InsertarCliente" useConfig="default">
    <sql>
    CALL AgregarCliente(:nombre, :domicilio, :id_cliente, :fecha);
   </sql>
    <param name="nombre" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" />
    <param name="domicilio" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" />
    <param name="id_cliente" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <param name="fecha" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="DATE" type="IN" optional="false" />
  </query>
  <query id="InsertarCuenta" useConfig="default">
    <sql>
      CALL InsertarCuenta(:numero_cuenta, :vigencia, :cliente_id, :banco_id);
    </sql>
    <param name="numero_cuenta" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" />
    <param name="vigencia" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="DATE" />
    <param name="cliente_id" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <param name="banco_id" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
  </query>
  <query id="InsertarSaldo" useConfig="default">
    <sql>
      CALL InsertarSaldo(:cuenta_id, :saldo);
    </sql>
    <param name="cuenta_id" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <param name="saldo" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="NUMERIC" />
  </query>
  <query id="InsertarMovimiento" useConfig="default">
    <sql>
      CALL InsertarMovimiento(?, ?, CURRENT_DATE);
    </sql>
    <param name="cuenta_id" ordinal="1" sqlType="INTEGER" />
    <param name="tipo_movimiento" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING" />
  </query>
  <resource method="POST" path="verificaredad">
    <call-query href="obtenerEdad">
      <with-param name="id_cliente" query-param="id_cliente" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="verificaredadcuenta">
    <call-query href="obtenerEdadCuenta">
      <with-param name="id_cuenta" query-param="id_cuenta" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="verificaredadsaldo">
    <call-query href="obtenerEdadSaldo">
      <with-param name="id_cuenta" query-param="id_cuenta" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="obtenerclientes">
    <call-query href="obtenerDatosClientes">
      <with-param name="id_cliente" query-param="id_cliente" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="obtenercuentas">
    <call-query href="ObtenerDatosCuenta">
      <with-param name="p_cuenta_id" query-param="id_cuenta" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="saldo">
    <call-query href="ObtenerDatosSaldo">
      <with-param name="p_saldo_id" query-param="saldo_id" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="insertar-cliente">
    <description />
    <call-query href="InsertarCliente">
      <with-param name="nombre" query-param="nombre" />
      <with-param name="domicilio" query-param="domicilio" />
      <with-param name="id_cliente" query-param="id_cliente" />
      <with-param name="fecha" query-param="fecha" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="insertar-cuenta">
    <description />
    <call-query href="InsertarCuenta">
      <with-param name="numero_cuenta" query-param="numero_cuenta" />
      <with-param name="vigencia" query-param="vigencia" />
      <with-param name="cliente_id" query-param="cliente_id" />
      <with-param name="banco_id" query-param="banco_id" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="insertar-saldo">
    <description />
    <call-query href="InsertarSaldo">
      <with-param name="cuenta_id" query-param="cuenta_id" />
      <with-param name="saldo" query-param="saldo" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <resource method="POST" path="insertar-movimiento">
    <description />
    <call-query href="InsertarMovimiento">
      <with-param name="cuenta_id" query-param="cuenta_id" />
      <with-param name="tipo_movimiento" query-param="tipo_movimiento" />
    </call-query>
  </resource>
  <config id="default">
    <property name="carbon_datasource_name">conn</property>
  </config>
</data>
```

My first 6 SQL queries are functions:

[image]

and the next 4 SQL queries are stored procedures:

[image]

I really must have 10 stored procedures and not 6 functions with 4 stored procedures; the reason for the which I used a function for do my first 6 SQL queries is for I can't do a

```
SELECT * FROM
```

with a stored procedure with my WSO2 REST dataservice, I only can do the last 4 SQL queries with stored procedures because I only can do an data insert form a stored procedure (with the CALL sentence), but with my first 6 statements, I can't get the rows of my tables through stored procedures.

In conclusion with my REST only can get row data use an function, I only can use stored procedures for inserting data.

What is the correct way for call stored procedures from a WSO2 REST data service?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to execute a stored procedure:

```
<sql>call someFunction(?)</sql>
```